# Single, Concurrent Job Spanning Multiple Nodes

Tags: jenkins

Given several nodes available Jenkins nodes (NodeA, NodeB, ...), is there a way to define a job such that it gets 2 nodes?

For example, Job1 gets assigned to NodeA & NodeD.

Comment: Do you mean that Job1 executes on both the Nodes concurrently else it should be able to execute on one of them ?

Comment: @Harsha Yes, concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

To make a job run TWICE - both on node-A AND node-D, use the Matrix-build Plugin (note it is a little tricky to configure and monitor).

To make a job run ONCE - either on node-A OR node-D, give those two nodes the same LABEL, and RESTRICT the job to run on that Label.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry I wasn't exactly clear:  I need it to run concurrently.

Comment: Please explain - should it run on Node-A and only afterwards on Node-B? (if they can run in parallel, my answer covers this)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to submit the job twice and use the [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) to choose which node to execute each job on. To submit both these jobs at the same time, you could try using the [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

Why are you trying to do this? Are you perhaps trying to use slave agents to install software? Perhaps you could consider using an orchestration tool like [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) (Which also has a [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin))